# Unable to deploy React JS application on Azure App service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I was going through the some of the links to deploy React Js application on the azure app service. But i am facing some problem while deploying the application.

I have added all the necessary things like `web.config` file to `public` folder and also added build directory to the workspace.

[Deploying web app on azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-03)

[Deploy Node.js to Azure App Service using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01?tabs=bash)

followed all the steps but getting below error when i try to deploy on azure app service. Before deploying i do run these commands

`npm run build`.

```
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762075166Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762079567Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762083667Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762088167Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762092268Z NodeJS Version : v12.16.3
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762096468Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-08-19T10:44:45.762100768Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:45.789282727Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2020-08-19T10:44:45.792738514Z Build Operation ID: |OtQwveNuO0A=.83a2ec6c_
2020-08-19T10:44:47.255197638Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960307930Z Running #!/bin/sh
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960336532Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960345833Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960355334Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960363235Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960370735Z export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g):$NODE_PATH
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960378436Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960386136Z      export PORT=8080
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960393937Z fi
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960401238Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960408638Z echo Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960416339Z extractionCommand="tar -xzf node_modules.tar.gz -C /node_modules"
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960424040Z echo "Removing existing modules directory from root..."
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960431740Z rm -fr /node_modules
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960439141Z mkdir -p /node_modules
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960446542Z echo Extracting modules...
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960453842Z $extractionCommand
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960461243Z export NODE_PATH="/node_modules":$NODE_PATH
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960468943Z export PATH=/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960476344Z if [ -d node_modules ]; then
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960483745Z     mv -f node_modules _del_node_modules || true
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960491245Z fi
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960498446Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960505546Z if [ -d /node_modules ]; then
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960524748Z     ln -sfn /node_modules ./node_modules 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960532849Z fi
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960540149Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960547550Z echo "Done."
2020-08-19T10:44:47.960554951Z npm start
2020-08-19T10:44:48.258132115Z Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2020-08-19T10:44:48.258154316Z Removing existing modules directory from root...
2020-08-19T10:44:48.260461807Z Extracting modules...
2020-08-19T10:44:48.262765098Z tar (child): node_modules.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
2020-08-19T10:44:48.262778299Z tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
2020-08-19T10:44:48.262970515Z tar: Child returned status 2
2020-08-19T10:44:48.262983816Z tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
2020-08-19T10:44:48.290740216Z Done.
2020-08-19T10:44:48.512406278Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2020-08-19T10:44:48.512836614Z npm info using npm@6.14.4
2020-08-19T10:44:48.512976126Z npm info using node@v12.16.3
2020-08-19T10:44:48.578204629Z npm info lifecycle adal_appp@0.1.0~prestart: adal_appp@0.1.0
2020-08-19T10:44:48.584464048Z npm info lifecycle adal_appp@0.1.0~start: adal_appp@0.1.0
2020-08-19T10:44:48.589867495Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:48.589881796Z > adal_appp@0.1.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2020-08-19T10:44:48.589887297Z > react-scripts start
2020-08-19T10:44:48.589891697Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:48.597331914Z sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2020-08-19T10:44:48.598224588Z npm info lifecycle adal_appp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
2020-08-19T10:44:48.599091959Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-19T10:44:48.599182267Z npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-08-19T10:44:48.599258573Z npm ERR! file sh
2020-08-19T10:44:48.599314678Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-08-19T10:44:48.600738196Z npm ERR! adal_appp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2020-08-19T10:44:48.600749897Z npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-08-19T10:44:48.600754497Z npm ERR! 
2020-08-19T10:44:48.600758798Z npm ERR! Failed at the adal_appp@0.1.0 start script.
2020-08-19T10:44:48.600763398Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-19T10:44:48.605436585Z npm timing npm Completed in 125ms
2020-08-19T10:44:48.605621800Z 
2020-08-19T10:44:48.605672405Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-19T10:44:48.605750311Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-19T10_44_48_601Z-debug.log
```

But the thing is the same application runs perfectly on local with below commands
`npm install` , `npm start`.

and just to verify whether the build which generated after `npm run build` works or not tried running the application from the build directory with below commands

```
npm install -g serve
```

then

```
serve -s build
```

then application opens up in browser.

Answer (score 11):

After doing some googling [found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594983/8081633). We need to add the below command in start up command in app service configuration for the Linux machines.

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon`

Steps:

```
- Go to App Service

- Navigate to Configuration

- Click on General Settings

- add the above command in Start up command, click on save 

- then restart the server
```

Answer (score 3):

From the log it looks like this is not a `Node.js` application, but a `react` application. Therefore `react-scripts start` is something the Azure App Service doesn't know anything about.

When you run a `react` app on localhost, it is powered by a `development server` which indeed is a `Node.js` server, but once you build it for production using `npm run build` it is nothing but an `index.html` file powered by a bunch of `.js` files and stylesheets. It has no web capabilities in itself.

`serve` on the other hand is a separate story. As per their description at `npmjs.com`: Assuming you would like to serve a static site, single page application or just a static file (no matter if on your device or on the local network), this package is just the right choice for you.

But this is not an Azure-like approach.

In production however, if you are using Azure, I recommend using Azure Blob Storage v2, which has static site hosting capabilities. Enable static site hosting in the blob storage and deploy the `build` folder in a container named `$web`. Ofcourse all of this is automatically done if you are using `vscode` with the `Azure plugin`. Assuming you have signed into Azure thru `vscode`, right-click on the `build` folder and select `deploy to static site`, follow the steps and you will be live with your react app.

However, if you do have a `Node.js express` backend alongside the `react` app, then you may put the `build` folder into the `Node.js` project at the same level as the `node_modules` folder and use static routing to have both frontend and backend work as a single package. Explicitly define a route to tell `express` to respond with the `index.html` file when asked for. Then you can deploy the whole package into an `Azure App Service`.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3006;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'))
});

// Then prefix your API endpoints with /api
app.get('/api/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  // Code to get user by id
});

app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {
  // Code to save user
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App bootstrapped on port ${port}...`);
});
```

When `/` is hit, then `index.html` is served. API calls served as defined with `/api/*`. I find this mechanism useful many a times.

Good luck.

Comment: the backend is spring boot. Yes its a react application. Before this have done multiple deployments but never faced this issue.