# Default Documents (custom 404) on Azure AppService Linux website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

**My Setup**

- Azure AppService Linux Plan
- VueJs app that I'm deploying to it
- Using Azure DevOps pipeline with "Azure AppService Deploy" task and Runtime Stack set to "1.0 (STATICSITE|1.0)"

**Problem:**
I need to set the 404 page to the index.html so Vue can take over the routing.
Currently if I deep link to a route in Vue I get this:
`404 Not Found  nginx/1.17.9`

Windows AppService plans support Default Documents but Linux doesn't (you can't combine Windows and Linux on a given AppServicePlan)
Static Websites has a routes.json approach for this (I don't want to use static websites, which is different from "static websites runtime in AppService")

Ideas on the easiest/lightest way to handle this?

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Configuration` ->`StartupCommand`: `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa` on portal.

For more details, Pls refer my answer in related post.

[Successful deployment still leads to default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708381/successful-deployment-still-leads-to-default-page/64709758#64709758)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  How supported/brittle do you think this is?  Their documentation doesn't seem to call this out anywhere that I could find.

Comment: @AndyV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377340/react-router-direct-links-not-working-on-azure-web-app-linux

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me ... at least not with a runtime of `1.0 (STATICSITE|1.0)`. Maybe this only works for NodeJS-Runtimes?