# Vue.js does not start in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I currently have a pipeline in Azure Dev Ops configured to build, copy, archive, and then deploy a Vue.js app to an Azure App Service running on Linux. When I SSH into the server I do see the outputs of the build appearing successfully in the wwwroot folder but when I pull up the URL of the App Service I'm just shown the default landing page. Below are screenshots of my wwwroot folder, the page I'm seeing when I pull up the URL and a copy of the yml file for the pipeline. Is there something else missing from the yml file that I need to add to tell the app service to start the vue.js app by chance, I'm fairly new to this stuff.

[image]

[image]

```
# Build a Node.js project that uses Vue.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/client-app

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/client-app/dist/**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    verbose: true

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1 (f719f76c-c23e-4160-aa93-914eb7851fdb)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'trashbot'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Comment: @JasonPan Yep that did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `startup command` on portal.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

*Related Posts:*

[1. Application is not loading when deployed via azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924180/application-is-not-loading-when-deployed-via-azure-app-service/66947617#66947617)

[2. Default Documents (custom 404) on Azure AppService Linux website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975898/default-documents-custom-404-on-azure-appservice-linux-website/66024272#66024272)